# How to access Java fx TextArea from outside the fxml controller in Testng class

Tags: java, fxml

I am trying to access the outTextScreen textarea in Worker class but getting error.

Context here is  executeWSButton method in fxmlcontroller class will call create worker method which will create a testng suite using InvokeTestng class.The suite will have worker class and i want to access the fxml textarea (outTextScreen ) inside the workerMain method.

I have tried to create object to fxmlcontoller class inside workerMain method but getting error. Could you please let me know how to access fxml elements inside worker class

FXMLController

```
        @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "deprecation" })
        public class FXMLController implements Initializable {

        Task copyWorker;
        @FXML
        Text textOutput;
        @FXML
        TextArea outputTextScreen;

        //   execute button event
        @FXML
        public void executeWSButton(ActionEvent event) {
                outputTextScreen.appendText(newLine + "Webservice Execution for Process:  Started" + newLine);
                executeWS.setDisable(true); 
                copyWorker = createWorker();        
        }

            public Task createWorker() {
                return new Task() {
                    @Override
                    protected Object call() throws Exception {
                        outputTextScreen.appendText(newLine + "Inside create worker" + newLine);
                        Invoke_TestNG_Classes ws = new Invoke_TestNG_Classes();
                        String output = ws.iterateThroughTestCases(inputfile_fp, GIfile_fp, testModule,excelPath);              
                        return true;
                    }
                };
            }

        }


    /*===============================================================================================================================
```

Invoke TestNG class

```
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public class Invoke_TestNG_Classes {
        static Map<Integer, String> col1Data = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>();
        static Map<Integer, String> col2Data = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>();
        static Map<String, String> finalKeyValuePair = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
        static List<String> testCaseList = new ArrayList<String>();
        //static String excelPath = "C:\\Automation_OCTS\\Data\\TestCaseExecution.xlsx";
        @SuppressWarnings({ "deprecation", "null" })
        public Map<String,String> readExcel(String excelPath) throws IOException {
            // Write a code to read test cases from excel and pass the arraylist to
            // testcase.add()
            Integer columnNo = null;
            String columnWanted;
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(
                    excelPath));
            @SuppressWarnings("resource")
            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fileInputStream);
            XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
            Row firstRow = sheet.getRow(0);

            for (Cell cell : firstRow) {
                columnWanted = "Test Case Name";
                if (cell.getStringCellValue().equals(columnWanted)) {
                    columnNo = cell.getColumnIndex();

                }
            }
            if (columnNo != null) {
                for (Row row : sheet) {
                    Cell c = row.getCell(columnNo);
                    if (c != null || c.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK) {

                        col1Data.put(row.getRowNum(), c.toString());
                    }
                }
            }
            for (int rowNumber = 0; rowNumber <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); rowNumber++) {
                XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(rowNumber);
                for (int columnNumber = 0; columnNumber <= row.getLastCellNum(); columnNumber++) {
                    XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(columnNumber);
                    if (cell != null) {

                        col2Data.put(row.getRowNum(), cell.toString());
                    }
                }

            }

            for (Entry<Integer, String> col1map : col1Data.entrySet())
                for (Entry<Integer, String> col2map : col2Data.entrySet()) {
                    if (col1map.getKey() != 0 && col2map.getKey() != 0
                            && col1map.getKey() == col2map.getKey()) {
                        finalKeyValuePair.put(col1map.getValue(),
                                col2map.getValue());
                    }
                }
            /*System.out.println("Excel Values mapped :");
            for (Entry<String, String> map : finalKeyValuePair.entrySet()) {
                System.out.println(map);
            }*/
            return finalKeyValuePair;

        }

        @Test
        public String iterateThroughTestCases(String testFile, String InterfaceFIle, String testModule,String excelPath) throws IOException {

            finalKeyValuePair= readExcel(excelPath);
            Iterator<Entry<String, String>> iterator = finalKeyValuePair.entrySet().iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                Entry<String, String> pair = iterator.next();
                if(pair.getValue().equals("Y"))
                {
                    testCaseList.add(pair.getKey());
                }

            }
            if(testCaseList.size()==0)
            {
                return "Mark atleast one test case with Flag as Y";
            }
                // Creating a new Suite
                XmlSuite suite = new XmlSuite();

                for (Integer i = 0; i < testCaseList.size(); i++) {

                  // Creating a new Test
                  XmlTest test = new XmlTest(suite);

                  // Set Test name
                  test.setName("test-number-" + i);

                  // New list for the parameters
                  Map<String, String> testParams = new HashMap<String, String>();

                  // Add parameter to the list
                  testParams.put("testFile", testFile);
                  testParams.put("InterfaceFile", InterfaceFIle);
                  // Add parameters to test
                  test.setParameters(testParams);

                  // New list for the classes
                  List<XmlClass> classes = new ArrayList<XmlClass>();

                  // Putting the classes to the list

                  classes.add(new XmlClass(testModule+testCaseList.get(i)));
                  // Add classes to test
                  test.setClasses(classes);


                }

                // New list for the Suites
                List<XmlSuite> suites = new ArrayList<XmlSuite>();

                // Add suite to the list
                suites.add(suite);

                // Creating the xml
                TestListenerAdapter tla = new TestListenerAdapter();
                TestNG tng = new TestNG();
                tng.setXmlSuites(suites);
                System.out.println(suite.toXml());

              //  tng.addListener(tla);
                tng.run();
                return "Completed";




        }

    }

/*==============================================================================
```

Worker Class

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class Worker extends ReporterBaseTest {




     @SuppressWarnings("restriction")
    @Parameters({ "testFile", "InterfaceFile" })
     @Test
    public  void workerMain(String inputfile_fp,String file_fp) throws Exception {

    //Error
        outputTextScreen.appendText(newLine + "Worker Webservice Execution for Process:  Started" + newLine);

        }

}`enter code here`
```

**strong text**

Comment: You need to pass the `outputTextScreen` as a reference to your workerMain method, or you need to make it available to other classes with the public keyword inside the `FXMLController` class like so `public TextArea outputTextScreen;`. Note that you may have to reference the `FXMLController` class to do that, like so: `mfFXMLController.outputTextScreen.appendText(newLine + "Worker Webservice Execution for Process:  Started" + newLine);`

Comment: I am getting error while trying to pass the outputTextScreen as a reference. I have declared it as public and in fxm controller class have created a object to worker class. Worker objWork=new Worker; objWork.workerMain(outputTextScreen ) .  I have updated the workerMain(TextArea outputTextScreen ) . But in fxml controller class only i am getting error 'The method workerMain(TextArea) in the type Worker is not applicable for the arguments ()' .  Could you please share any sample code for passing the fxml elements as reference. Thanks for your suggestions.